# Creating a random array and fetching the value in an index and the index when a value is entered but information fetched is wrong

Tags: c#

For some reason my program won't print the correct index that corresponds with the value and the correct value that corresponds with the array.

```
private static void askNumber(int[] numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++) 
    {
        if(number == numbers[i]) //if the user input is equal to the number at the index
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your index for your number {0} is {1}", number, i);
        }
    }
}

private static void randomNumberArray(int upperLimit, int[] numbers)
{
    Random randInt = new Random(); //random function
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = randInt.Next(upperLimit); //random number is chosen between 0 and upperLimit
    }
    foreach(int i in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
    }
}

private static void askIndex(int[] numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index: ");
    int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The value at index {0} is {1}", index, numbers[index]); //fetches number at an index entered
}
```

All of the code I have put in here doesn't output the correct index and number. I have also included the random number generator for the array. I just can't seem to find the problem and I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code *supposed* to do, and what is "wrong" about what the code is doing currently? (I suspect that in `randomNumberArray()` where you have `foreach (int i in numbers) Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);` it should probably be just: `foreach (int i in numbers) Console.WriteLine(i);`)

Comment: Where is the code that links these methods to each other? Also, your `randomNumberArray` method gets passed an array, reassigns every index, then prints the _new_ values. I'm guessing this isn't desired functionality...

Comment: How are you calling these 3 methods in your program, what is expected output and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach(int i in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Assuming you want to print an array of generated numbers:

```
foreach(int i in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```